# Detect Twitter submit Android

Tags: c#, android, twitter

I am currently writing an android app.

I intend to run my application in the background of my phone and I want to be able to detect when I submit a post using the Twitter app on the same device.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Not unless Twitter sends out a broadcast whenever it posts, which is unlikely.  Now what you may be able to do is use the Twitter API and see if there's a way to get a notification of when someone posts on your account.  Haven't looked at that API so I'm not sure.

Comment: Twitter should (presumably) be using a POST request when a Tweet is sent from within the app. If, for some reason, you had access to network information within the device you could look for those requests and then do something.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have checked the API and alas no fruition of an answer :(

Comment: "on the same device": is it because you have the same Twitter app on other devices of the same type (Android)? So that's why the `source` field of the [tweet](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) isn't enough, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the OAuth customer key in the Twitter Application Management  (url https://apps.twitter.com/),
- that is one of the preliminary steps to implement the authentication- 
you'll define there the **source** field (look for instance at the documentation from https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) that will be reported in all the tweets posted by the API of your newly created Twitter app.
So when you get your tweets, you'll detect the ones posted by that specific app (on your phone).
More generally I have published an open source Twitter app for Android on github: https://github.com/giuliohome/TweetSearch just look at the API call where I retrieve the source of a Tweet for more details, basically a simple

```
jsonObject.getString("source")
```

By the same field you can detect the tweets posted by the official Twitter app for Android on the same device - assuming it is the only Android device from where your username is twitting with the target app, otherwise I'm not aware of any *legitimate* and standard way to detect the physical device

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying - So if I 1. post with the official Twitter app, I can then 2. use my app to state where the tweet came from (my device). Only problem with this is the Tweet has already gone out and I would need to run a check against existing Tweets? What I need to do as stated in the question is detect when the Tweet is submitted (perhaps have my own app show an alert). Or am I missing something in your answer?

Comment: @Ebikeneser You're correct. For your app to show an alert, it could install a service and periodically check the latest tweets (testing if they are from the target source), more or less like the notifications for the new incoming emails

Comment: But is there a way to to it without retrospectively checking the Tweets? Like just detect when I push the submit button on the official Twitter app?

Comment: Nope afaik and that'd eventually be unreliable after a possible update of the official Twitter app. Anyway I fail to see what is the concrete difference: maybe in terms of seconds needed to send the notification?

Comment: Well after reading the Twitter api, that call to check all new tweets is rate limited, therefore would you be able to check every Tweet every second without bursting that limit?

Comment: Which rate limit? Say [900 requests in 15 minutes](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline): it means that each 15 * 60 / 900 = 1 second you can potentially send a request, returning  "up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets"... :-) how many status updates is your username posting per second??

Comment: ok bounty awarded well done, i guess this would be the best solution with out interfering with the official app which probably isnt possible anyways.